# Google Extension Manifest to Disable Styles on Pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, styles, manifest

I am trying to create an extension to disable all styles on a page, but it is not working.
My javascript is valid, as well as my manifest and html code. Any ideas?
Thank you

This is my updated Manifest code

```
{

"name": "Styles Disable Button",
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "1.0",
"description": "This function will enable users to deactivate all styles from 
 the webpages they are opening.",

"browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "styledisable.html"
     },

"content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["removestyles.js"]
    }
    ]
 }
```

This is the `Javascript` I am using (which only gets rid of styles on some websites)

```
function removeStyles(el) {
    el.removeAttribute('style');

    if(el.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for(var child in el.childNodes) {
        /* filter element nodes only */
        if(el.childNodes[child].nodeType == 1)
            removeStyles(el.childNodes[child]);
        }
    }
 }

 var stylesheets = document.getElementsByTagName('link'), i, sheet;

 var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
 while(images.length > 0) {
 images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
 }

 for(i in stylesheets) {
 sheet = stylesheets[i];

  if(sheet.getAttribute('type').toLowerCase() == 'text/css')
    sheet.parentNode.removeChild(sheet);
  }

  removeStyles(document.body);
```

This is my HTML 5 code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Style Disable Button</title>
  <style>
    body {
        width: 400px;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    footer {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Lighter Page Faster Download</h1>
<p>
    This function will enable users to deactivate all styles from the webpages they are opening.
    <br>Lighter pages for faster download and connectivity.
</p>
<p>    
    Esta funcion permitira a los usuarios de deactivar todos los stiles de paginas web que estan abriendo.
    <br>Paginas mas legeras para una descarga y una conectivitad mas rapida.
</p>
<p>
    Cette fonction permettra aux utilisateurs de desactiver tous les styles a partir des pages web, ils ouvrent.
    <br>Pages plus legeres pour un telechargement et un connectivite plus rapide.
</p>

  <br>
  <br>

  <footer>
   Francesco Volpi &copy; 2015
  </footer>
```

Comment: What? It doesn't work but it works?

Comment: You want to disable the styles only in one page or everywhere? And when you say styles, what do you mean? All the computed css (inline and files) or only `.css` files?

Comment: I want to disable styles on a single page, like you would on safari for instance (Safari>Develop>Disable Styles or in Firefox>CSS>Disable All Styles). And when I say styles, I literally mean everything, so that a page is left with only its html code and displays just that.

Comment: I have changed my Manifest code and it now lets my disable styles but not images and only on certain pages (my content script may not be matching all urls)

Comment: Also, when I said that my code was working, I meant to say that it is valid